# Is there a syntax highlight plugin for Scheme language for rendering in browser?

Tags: javascript, scheme, syntax-highlighting

While I was searcing, the word 'scheme' looks like a bad keyword for there's something called  'color scheme'..

And I found the highlight.js plugin, only Lisp was supported?
http://softwaremaniacs.org/media/soft/highlight/test.html

Is there any library you would suggest to highlight Scheme code in browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow uses [Google Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting. It [supports Lisp-like languages](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html#langs) including Scheme with [the `lang-lisp.js` extension](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-lisp.js).

Once the scripts are added to your page, the markup would look like this:

```html
<pre class="prettyprint lang-scm">(define five 5)</pre>
```

**[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/B4P4D/embedded/result,html/)**